# How do I implement a CSS framework Shopify's Liquid theme language?

Tags: css, liquid, shopify-template

I am creating a workflow to start building themes for Shopify, but can't figure out how to implement a CSS framework.

What do I need to do to get one going and what would prevent me from using one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any css framework will work.

To add it just go to: Admin > Themes > Template Editor > theme.liquid
And add it.
Ex. bootstrap (add it inside of the head tag):

```
{{ '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' | script_tag }}
{{ '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
```